# What is a good solution for an intranet video portal (YouTube-like) site?

Tags: intranet, video

I would like an easy-to-setup site to handle videos to be viewed internally by my company.  YouTube is essentially the perfect solution except for its being public.  I'm looking for a place where a few people can upload videos, and the system will return a page where they can watch that video in a browser.

I figure this would involve a dedicated Web server to run the Web application and process the videos.  I've searched and I don't think such a system exists, but I perhaps there's one out there in its infancy that doesn't rank high on Google yet.

Essentially the site I'm looking for is what MediaWiki is to Wikis, or what StackExchange is to Q&A sites, but for videos.

Answer (score 5):

You could subscribe to Google Apps for Business which includes Google Video

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/collaboration.html

Answer (score 3):

[VideoLan](http://www.videolan.org/) makes a very good client, and though I haven't used it, it appears to include "a complete streaming server, with extended features (video on demand, on the fly transcoding, ...)"

Definitely less turnkey than the above, however, but open-source.

Comment: The VideoLan Client (sometimes better know by VLC) is my favorite video player, it's simple and just works. Its list of supported codec and access methods is impressive to say the least. I've used their server for simple things, but I see no reason it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I found a good solution, for very little money:  www.vimeo.com.  I can purchase a year subscription for $60 and get the privacy options I need.  I don't need to install / manage a server which is a plus.  And I can embed the videos elsewhere - our intranet, our Web site, etc.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.techsmith.com and / or www.onstreammedia.com

Comment: upvoting because it was along the lines of what I was looking for.  Techsmith's offering wasn't perfect mainly because in testing the video playback was very very slow.  Most likely that is because they do not encode the video, but it made me worry that they have bandwidth issues...

Answer (score 1):

You didnt mention zero cost in your question - if you are willing to pay for SharePoint, the Podcasting Kit for SharePoint is an all-in-one solution that might fit your needs.

http://www.codeplex.com/pks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out Apple's [Quicktime Streaming Server](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/streamingserver/). It's pretty powerful, but it does require you to get an XServe and a copy of OS X Server.

Answer (score 0):

Hmn. I don't have a good solution to this, except to say that when we needed something similar we developed it in-house. Don't forget that you need a streaming server of some sort; we use Helix for some formats and Flash Media Server for adobe flash video.

I think iTunes offers a 'private site' package through it's itunes store, which might be cheaper. Outsourcing it would definitely be cheaper than building even a limited-use machine in-house.

Comment: Outsourcing brings in the issue of bandwidth though.  By keeping it in house, you have significantly less bandwidth constraints, being that you can get gigabit to each user for fairly cheap these days.

Comment: Yep, but we have $100k in server equipment and licenses plus several years of developer time. At that cost point, bandwith becomes cheap. The poor man's alternative would be to just drop files in file shares and let users download and view them -- but since the O.P. wanted a web-based solution that allows users to submit content, a file share doesn't answer the stated question. My point was that the only thing that may fit the price point between "poor man" and "youtube" is outsourcing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any all in one packages that include sites.  I believe they're all homegrown at the moment.  We've been using [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) for a while now.  I allow users to upload their own videos to the server (securely of course), provide them with their embed code, and then they can embed the video where ever they want.  This would give you the streaming, but not the pre-made site like you want.  There are also open source alternatives to Adobe's product, like Red5 and such.  But we were looking for Actionscript capabilities and solid support.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use silverlight, [Video.Show](http://www.codeplex.com/videoshow) is open source and fully functional. Oops, I just noticed:

> All video is hosted at Silverlight
>   Streaming, which gives you 4GB storage
>   and 700 Kbps bandwidth via Microsoft's
>   worldwide Content Delivery Network.

I believe that accounts are still available for free at [Silverlight Streaming](http://silverlight.live.com/). It might be something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](http://www.serviio.org/), it is pretty nice - Also the paid version has a built-in browser viewer application so it seems pretty decent to me!